# Converting time_point to float

Tags: c++

I've this

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point mElapsedTime;
```

And I want to convert the difference between this time_point and another to a float, is that possible?

Comment: What is that conversion supposed to yield? Suppose `mElapsedTime` (weird name for a time *point* to begin with) contains the time at which you posted your question, what floating point value would you want to get from that?

Comment: I have another time point, which is mStartedTime, and I want to get the difference between those two variables in the form of a float

Comment: That's a different question than the one in the question box above already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [minus operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/operator_arith2) is overloaded for a pair of `time_points` to produce a floating point `duration`. If you want an integral duration, you can use a [duration cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast).

```
// Option 1
std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli> diff = mElapsedTime - mStartedTime;
// Access the float with .count
std::cout << diff.count() << '\n';

// Option 2
// Or convert to a discrete unit of time, with underlying integral type
std::chrono::milliseconds integral_diff =
   std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(mElapsedTime - mStartedTime);
std::cout << integral_diff.count() << '\n';

// What actually is std::chrono::milliseconds?
static_assert(
   std::is_same_v<std::chrono::milliseconds, std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::milli>>);
```

I've left the types in my example above as I feel it helps see what we're dealing with, in real world code I would use auto, especially for the duration cast.